# curse.execute in if statement python

Tags: python

I have question, possible make if statement with curse.execute in the if statement?
I need get number on rows, for it my code bellow

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from test WHERE email = '{0}'".format(json.dumps(email)))
time_check = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

so im getting 16, its working fine, but i need check by time like 8 am
it will be very "hardcoding" if i do a lot of

```
   cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from test WHERE time='8:00:00.000' and email = '{0}'".format(json.dumps(email)))
    time_check1 = cursor.fetchone()[0]
   cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from test WHERE time='8:30:00.000' and email = '{0}'".format(json.dumps(email)))
    time_check2 = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

so, i want put what in if statement, and i have problem with how to do in if statement `cursor.fetchone` function with `curse.execute`?
if statement function be checking if in what time exist less then two rows.
I dont want do like this

```
if (time_check1  < 2)
{
}
```

I want make something like this

```
if (cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from test WHERE time='8:30:00.000' and email = '{0}'".format(json.dumps(email)))< 2)
{
}
```

Im using python and this in flask project.
Any idea how to solve it? or something another way to check it?

Comment: I'm going to let you know right now that this is a bad idea in general. Debugging is going to be a royal pain if something doesn't work

Comment: can you tell me then better way check if rows in database exist less then two rows? by specific time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it is maybe to use a function

```
def execute_and_fetch_one(cursor, statement):
    cursor.execute(statement)
    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Then you can call it inside an if statement

```
if (execute_and_fetch_one(cursor, "SELECT COUNT(*) from test WHERE time='8:30:00.000' and email = '{0}'".format(json.dumps(email))) < 2)
```

Regardless, you normally shouldn't use .format to format your SQL queries, since that is prone to SQL injection, search online what is the alternative way for that with the package that you are using

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't want to put a query execution in an if statement. This can lead to trouble later when you need to troubleshoot. Create a general function that will handle your executes. You can create a single function that handles execute, fetch_all, fetch_one, etc. Or you can create multiple functions and handle the results based on what you need.

Depending on what your database is, you can do something like this (mysql as an example):

Example Pseudo Code (note the use of DictCursor):

```
import pymysql

def fetch_one(sql):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=database)
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    ret_ = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return ret_
```

Then you can create a statement like this:

```
sql = "SELECT count(*) as 'count' from [table] where [...]"

ret_ = fetch_one(sql)

print(ret_['count'])
```

Then you can process the results. I personally use DictCursor to handle the results as a dictionary. I find it easier to process. Although there are other ways of doing it.